# Staying logged in with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, forms, selenium, submit

I am trying to log into a website and then once logged in navigate to a different page on the website remaining logged in, using Selenium. However, when I try to navigate to the different page, I found I have become logged off.

I believe this is because I do not understand how the `webdriver.Firefox().get()` function works exactly.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from Code.Other import XMLParser

#Initialise driver and go to webpage
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
URL = 'http://www.website.com'
driver.get(URL)

#Login
UserName = XMLParser.XMLParse('./Config.xml','UserName')
Password = XMLParser.XMLParse('./Config.xml','Password')
element = driver.find_elements_by_id('UserName')
element[0].send_keys(UserName)
element = driver.find_elements_by_id('Password')
element[0].send_keys(Password)
element = driver.find_elements_by_id('Submit')
element[0].click()

#Go to new page
URL = 'http://www.website.com/page1'
driver.get(URL)
```

Unfortunately I am navigated to the new page but I am no longer logged in. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there no way for you to `click` on an `element` to reach the second page after login? Does the same occur if you do that rather than using the second `driver.get()`?

Comment: If I search for the link and use `click`, I remain signed in (y). This feels more like a workaround though.

Comment: Think about how your user would be using your website - that is what `Selenium/Webdriver` is trying to replicate. Would you user open the base URL, login and then type in a new URL OR would they open the 'base' URL, login and then click a link to reach the second page?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like website doesn't have enough time to react on your submit in authorization form. You  click `submit` but you don't wait for response and open another url.

Wait until some event after login (like getting cookies or some changes in DOM or just `time.sleep`) and only then go to another page.

P.S.: if it won't help, try to check your cookies after login and after you open new url, maybe it's problem with authorization backend or webdriver